# How to count page in file doc, docx use ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I am having trouble counting the number of pages doc and docx when inputting a file. Do you have any workarounds that can help me? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use [yomu](https://github.com/yomurb/yomu) gem and get number of pages from metadata

```
doc_data = File.read 'sample_file.docx'
metadata = Yomu.read :metadata, doc_data
page_numbers = metadata['Page-Count']
```